# Springdata elastic search not able to support empty spaces in wildcard bool query

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:4.1.0 with elasticsearch 7.8.1.

I have a requirement where I need to lookup partial search for multiple attributes. I have implemented wildcard bool queries which is working fine except it is not able to do lookup for empty spaces.

Here is my actual query:

```
GET /maintenance_logs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "vinNumber.keyword": "DH34ASD7SDFF84742"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "organizationId": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "dtcCode": {
              "value": "*Cabin*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "subSystem": {
              "value": "*Cabin*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "maintenanceActivity": {
              "value": "*Cabin*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "description": {
              "value": "*Cabin*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my SearchRequest:

```
public static SearchRequest buildSearchRequest(final String indexName,
                                                   final SearchRequestDTO dto,
                                                   final String vinNumber,
                                                   final Integer organizationId, Pageable pageable) {
        try {
            final int page = pageable.getPageNumber();
            final int size =  pageable.getPageSize();
            final int from = page <= 0 ? 0 : pageable.getPageSize();

            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indexName);
            SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
            BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();


            final QueryBuilder vinQuery = QueryBuilders.termQuery("vinNumber.keyword", vinNumber);
            final QueryBuilder orgIdQuery = QueryBuilders.termQuery("organizationId", organizationId);

            boolQueryBuilder.must(vinQuery);
            boolQueryBuilder.must(orgIdQuery);


            boolQueryBuilder.minimumShouldMatch(1);

            boolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("dtcCode", "*" + dto.getSearchTerm() + "*"));
            boolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("subSystem", "*" + dto.getSearchTerm() + "*"));
            boolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("maintenanceActivity", "*" + dto.getSearchTerm() + "*"));
            boolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("description", "*" + dto.getSearchTerm() + "*"));

            searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);

            searchSourceBuilder
                    .from(from)
                    .size(size)
                    .sort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("statsDate")
                                  .order(SortOrder.DESC));

            searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
            return searchRequest;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This works fine except I am unable to search for strings like "Cabin pressure".

Comment: what are the mappings for these fields, especially the description (where I suppose you search for "cabin pressure")

Comment: and btw - this is no Spring Data Elasticsearch as you are using Elasticsearch classes and code to build your query.

Comment: @Document(indexName = "maintenance_logs", createIndex = true)
public class MaintenanceLog {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String maintenanceActivity;

    private String vinNumber;

    private Integer organizationId;

    private String partitionYear;

    private String dtcCode;

    private String subSystem;

    private String description;

    private Integer odometer;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to search a multi-token value like "Cabin pressure" to be findable with a wildcard query using "*Cabin pressure*" you  need to define it in the mapping as being of type `keyword`.

The wildcard search searches for single **terms** that match the wildcard expression, and "Cabin pressure" by default is split into two terms, "Cabin" and "pressure".

In Spring Data Elasticsearch the way to do this is to use `@Field(type = FieldType.Keyword`, but you'd either need to delete and recreate the index to have the new mapping applied, or you need to create a new index and reindex the existing one into the new. That's because index mappings cannot be updated and in your existing index the type is by default defined as `text`.

And, if you store "Cabin pressure" as one term - type `keyword` - don't forget that this will be a different thing than "cabin pressure". Keywords are not normalized, so that upper and lower case differences matter.

Comment: Great. Tha ks I'll check and let you know.

Comment: Here are the changes that i made: 
  boolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("dtcCode.keyword", "*" + dto.getSearchTerm() + "*").boost(1));
            boolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("subSystem.keyword", "*" + dto.getSearchTerm() + "*").boost(1));

----------------------------------
@Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String dtcCode;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String subSystem;

----
It still does not seem to work.  I guess I will read the manual bit more details.